# page access only for login user

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm creating one web application with two page, (ie) login.aspx and main.aspx..

i want to set login permission to access main.aspx page.. if we browse the main.aspx. we should get the **error or please login....** message. kindly give me some solutions.

i create the login page with single user, the username is predefined. if we click the login button it check with username and password then it will proceed to main.aspx page.the login button event code is as bellow, please suggest me some solution.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["username"] = txtUser.Text;
    string username = txtUser.Text;
    string pass = txtPwd.Text;

    if (username == "Imosuser" &&  pass == "imos@123")
    {
     Response.Redirect("main.aspx");
        }
        else
        {

            ldltext.Text = "Please check the username and password";
        }

    }


}
```

thanks in advance....

Comment: Start [here](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/security).

Comment: I don't even understand what you are trying to ask?

Comment: what is the question ??

Comment: my question is user can't access the main.aspx page directly only  if they login through the login.aspx page, can access it. @Adam

Comment: Are they able to now? If so just check if they are authenticated in the main.aspx

Comment: i'm new to asp.net and c#, so only i created two pages, authentication are all in login page itself. if login successful user can access the main page. but here i deployed the application in IIS, where i browse the url it will goes to login page fine. eg: (server ip:port number/main.aspx) it will directly accessible. with out login. i want to restrict main page. now can you understand the scenario....@Adam

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of `web.config` file and then add the following code which will prevent people from accessing the page if they're not logged in

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

<location path="main.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>

</configuration>
```

I also suggest you read **[this](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config)** blog, as it highlights setting authorization rules.

Comment: if i add the above line of code in web.config, i can access the main page directly. no difference in it. i already read the blog you suggested @izzy